# submit and close modal at same time

Tags: javascript

We have a form within a modal window.

I have a submit button, which saves to db. And I would like to simultaneously close the modal window.

The function for close is correct, just not my usage lol.

```
<input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Thumbnail" id="save_thumb" onclick="$.lightbox().close();" />
```

The modal window , contains iframe with php / html within it, this form is part of that iframed html code.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

To close the dialog when the element with ID `save_thumb` is clicked:

```
$('#save_thumb').click(function ()
{
    $.lightbox().close();
});
```

You might want to bind to its parent form's submit event, however, since keyboard events won't trigger the `click` handler:

```
$('#my_form_id').submit(function ()
{
    $.lightbox().close();
});
```

Whichever you decide on, make sure to wrap it up in a [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).

Answer (score 1):

Use the bind function,

```
$(function() {
  $("#save_thumb").bind("click", function() {
    $.lightbox().close();
  });
});
```

Comment: The selector is incorrect (this is jQuery, not Prototype). Also, why use `.bind('click', ...)` instead of `.click(...)`?

Comment: oops, fixed.  i tend to prefer bind for consistency of syntax when using lots of different types of events..

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript to your file and remove the onclick attribute on your button. Make sure the javascript is added inside  tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save_thumb').click(function (){
        $.lightbox().close();
    });
});
```